# How to get notified on CheckBoxPreference state change?

Tags: android, checkbox, sharedpreferences, preferenceactivity

I need to set/unset listener dynamically in response to a [Preference CheckBox](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/CheckBoxPreference.html) user setting change.

One approach I have seen is to use [onSharedPreferenceChanged()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9719541/preferenceactivity-using-onsharedpreferencechanged) and check for that checkbox's key.

But somehow this looks to me inefficient. I was thinking more in the direction of setting some kind of listener on the class derived from `PreferenceActivity`. Perhaps [onContentChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html#onContentChanged%28%29)?

Which approach would you recommend and why?

Can you point to a sample working code?

Comment: Have you tried [`setOnCheckedChangeListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener))?

Comment: @slybloty See my comment to @Yawus below. How do I use `setOnCheckedChangeListener()` for a `<CheckBoxPreference>`? Note the difference from `<CheckBox>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should implement [`OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html). And then set up a listener to catch key changes:

```
getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
```

The you should be able to retrieve the checked changes:

```
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,String key) 
{

}
```

Comment: +1. Are you suggesting that the first approach I mentioned in my question is the only way to go? Or the best one? [PreferenceActivity.html#onContentChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html#onContentChanged%28%29) won't cut it?

Comment: It might work as well. I can't give you an exact answer since I haven't tried it myself. But I suggest implementing the listener.

Comment: OK. I will never know whether onContentChanged() works better because I just implemented OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() and it works fine. One day, when I have more time to experiment and benchmark...

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html). Using the XML file, you can set a method to be executed when the widget is clicked. Setting `android:onClick = foo` will execute the method `foo` when the widget is clicked, passing it the parameter `View v`, `v` being the View that was clicked.

Comment: Your suggestion is great for `<CheckBox>` in the context of layout. I am referring to `<CheckBoxPreference>` in the context of PreferenceScreen. But I think that I just found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386832/android-checkbox-listener . Actually, even that is for the layout context, not the PreferenceScreen.

Comment: All right, good for you that you found the answer. Guess I should've read a bit more deeply.

Comment: Actually I didn't. I celebrated too early.